# Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   '>' com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is the error I'm getting, I've recently updated my java to 1.8.0.65(if you couldn't tell) and I've updated the studio but after this and after I added mysql connector(not sure which is causing the issue) the latest 5.1.37.

This is how my build.gradle looks

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "alexxela.xela.geitkontroll2000"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

I added the "compileOptions" after i didn't get it to work, but to no avail..

anyone gotten issues simular and know how to fix it?(I've googled and found several types of same error but they don't seem to work(not 100% same error))

Comment: "Is the error I'm getting" -- scroll up in your Gradle Console to find the actual source of the error.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry, poor english. That is the error I am getting. I'll fix it thanks.

Comment: No, I mean, **scroll up in your Gradle Console to find the actual source of the error**.

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe this is what you mean "...while parsing com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42CallableStatement.class" correct?

Comment: Well, that seems more promising as being related to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Because the library file have already been in expansion ".jar"